# Why does the pdf file converted from epub by Calibre miss some contents?

Tags: pdf, calibre, ebooks, epub

I have [an epub file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3361630500e7f21be86c51cc78285e7920231026170857/2fd538b227b66b08b4910e0e4d9e0c5e20231026170858/73e46d?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid), which I converted into a pdf file using Calibre's `ebook-convert` command. But the resulted pdf file misses an article named "The Conquest, War, and Genocide", for *Joshua* in *The Old Testament*. I was wondering why? Can anyone convert the epub file into a pdf file without missing contents?

```
$ ebook-convert --version
..ebook-convert-wrapped-wrapped (calibre 5.42.0)
Created by: Kovid Goyal <kovid@kovidgoyal.net>
```

Here is the screenshot of the missed article in the pdf file

[image]

and the one of the article in the original epub file viewed in Calibre:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This honestly sounds like a bug that should probably be reported to Calibre https://calibre-ebook.com/bugs.

However, you can try installing the newest version of Calibre instead of using the one from the repos.  Even Calibre states not to use the one from the Distributions as they can be [buggy and outdated](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

*These instructions come directly from Calibre themselves.  https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux*

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```